# Wrap React-Bootstrap Scrollable Modal in Formik Form

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, formik

I'm wrapping a React-Bootstrap scrollable `Modal` in a Formik `Form` in order to have the buttons in the `Modal.Footer` submit the form. However when I wrap the `Modal.Body` and `Modal.Footer` in a `Form` element it stops the content from being scrollable. Any idea how to wrap the modal in a form and preserve the style? Here's the code:

```
<Modal show={this.props.displayModal} onHide={this.reset} dialogAs="div">
    <Formik initialValues={{}} validationSchema={validationSchema} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <Form>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Add Item/Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>CONTAINS FORM INPUTS</Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button type="submit" variant="primary">
                    Save
                </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Form>
    </Formik>
</Modal>
```

I did attempt place the `Modal` in the `Form`, but this leads to the `Modal` being rendered outside the form element in the HTML. eg:

```
<Formik initialValues={this.initialValues} validationSchema={this.validationSchema} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <Form>
        <Modal show={this.props.displayModal} onHide={this.reset} dialogAs="div">
           ...
        </Modal>
    </Form>
</Formik>
```

Comment: Hey, did you aim to close the modal after submitting? I'm struggling to find a way not to close the modal after clicking on Save because I have other content to display. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't remember the exact behaviour. AFAIK you should be able to override the form submission behaviour so the form doesn't close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this issue I had to add a `Modal.Dialog` inside the `Form` and then change the `dialogAs` prop of the `Modal` to a `div`. This leads to the `Modal.Dialog` handling the scrollable styling, which I wanted to preserve.

```
<Modal show={this.props.displayModal} onHide={this.reset} dialogAs="div">
    <Formik initialValues={{}} validationSchema={validationSchema} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <Form>
            <Modal.Dialog scrollable size="lg">
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Add Item/Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>CONTAINS FORM INPUTS</Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button type="submit" variant="primary">
                        Save
                    </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal.Dialog>
        </Form>
    </Formik>
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same problem and the solution I found was to put the Formik tags inside the Modal tag and pass a style="overflow-y: scroll" into the Form tag. Something like this:

```
<Modal
    isOpen={modal}
    toggle={toggle}
    centered
    className="modal-dialog"
    scrollable (optional*)
    size="lg"
  >
    <FormikContext.Provider value={methods}>
      <Form className="scrollable">
           <ModalHeader>
               Your header or title
            </ModalHeader>
            <ModalBody>CONTAINS FORM INPUTS</ModalBody>
            <ModalFooter>
                <Button type="submit" variant="primary">
                    Save
                </Button>
            </ModalFooter>
        </Form>
    </FormikContext.Provider>
  </Modal>
```

into style.css:

```
 .scrollable {
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
```

*methods* is a const with initialValues, schemaValidations and onSubmit

```
    const methods = useFormik({
    validationSchema: mySchema,
    initialValues: {
      name: data?.name || '',
      email: data?.email || '',
    },
    enableReinitialize: true,
    onSubmit: (data) => {
      console.log('data', data);
    },
  });
```

**scrollable* prop is for scroll inside the modal, if you want a full screen scrolling, dont use it